# Unable to send audio attachment to FB Messenger via bot

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am unable to send an audio attachment via botbuilder. I am on the latest version of the botbuilder. Below is the snippet of code I am using. I have tried all different options but nothing is working. Can someone shed some light please on why this is happening ?

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session).
sourceEvent( 
{facebook: { attachment: 
{ type: "audio", payload: 
{ url:"https://petersapparel.com/bin/clip.mp3" } } } }); 
session.send(msg);
```

I am recieving the following error

```
Error: Request to 'https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/1106358962795256-204426340019460/activities/38b93pDlg4a' failed: [400] Bad Request at Request._callback (/workspace/FranceSayBot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:413:46) at Request.self.callback (/workspace/FranceSayBot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22) at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) at Request.emit (events.js:191:7) at Request.<anonymous> (/workspace/FranceSayBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1081:10) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at Request.emit (events.js:188:7) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/workspace/FranceSayBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1001:12) at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16) at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use SourceEvent.  Send it as an attachment:

```
// Create and send attachment
var attachment = {
    contentUrl: 'https://petersapparel.com/bin/clip.mp3',
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    name: 'My video clip'
};

var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .addAttachment(attachment);

session.send(msg);
```